# Why is the representation of the mesh different from the actual mesh?

Tags: mesh, wireframe

I think early on in my modeling I did something that is causing the wireframe representation of some of the lines to show up in a different place than they are on the actual mesh. I've applied all transforms.

See how in the object view the curves represented on the inside of the model don't match up with the actual mesh? Any ideas what is wrong?

[image: object mesh]

[image: object view]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I've put it on my website here: http://suso.suso.org/mediafiles/cassette.blend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>, you have an hidden edge.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help